# Probabilistic Robotics by Thurn: Velocity motion model. Detailed derivation for eq. 18

Tags: mapping, kinematics, motion, velocity, geometry

In the book, The equation for finding center of circle is denoted in eq. 5.17, which is as
$$\begin{pmatrix} x^* \\ y^* \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} -\lambda \text{sin} \theta \\ \lambda \text{cos} \theta \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} {x+x' \over 2}+ \mu(y-y') \\ {y-y' \over 2}+ \mu(x'-x) \end{pmatrix} $$
, and stated that the solution for $$\mu$$ is as
$$\mu = {1 \over 2} { (x-x’) \text{cos} \theta + (y-y’) \text{sin} \theta \over (y-y’) \text{cos}\theta - (x - x’) \text{sin} \theta}$$.

Does anyone have idea about the geometric and how to get this solution?. Also I wonder that $$\lambda$$ from the first above eq is called "unknown" variable, how is this variable derived from the geometric perception.?

Thank you.